# How to modify html element on page load in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a button element on the popup.html file that I want to modify on page load via the content.js file. However, when I tried the below code it did not work (text button text does not change).

How do I change the button text when the content loaded?

popup.html:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="to-modify-button">no text</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("to-modify-button");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (
    request,
    sender,
    sendResponse
) {
    if (request.theme === "dark") {
        btn.textContent = "Disable dark mode";
    } else {
        btn.textContent = "Enable dark mode";
    }
});
```

content.js:

```js
(() => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ theme: "dark" });
})();
```

Comment: Check the console log by right-clicking the web page that injected the content script and selecting inspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push to popup. pull from popup.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "content_scripts + popup",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="to-modify-button">no text</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("to-modify-button");

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "message", (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.theme === "dark") {
      btn.textContent = "Disable dark mode";
    } else {
      btn.textContent = "Enable dark mode";
    }
  });
});
```

content.js

```js
console.log("content.js");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(message);
  sendResponse({ theme: "dark" });

  return true;
});
```